# Meaning of じゃ無いんじゃないかって

Tags: meaning

I'm not sure how to understand/translate the phrase 「じゃ無いんじゃないかって」

> それはあんまり良いことじゃ無いんじゃないかって

For more context, previous sentences translated to:

> You always had those (headphones) on when you were walking right?
> Even during the times you didn't use them, they were definitely in your bag.

I understand that it's talking about how that something is not very good?
But I'm thrown off by that phrase

Comment: Related: [Meaning of じゃないんじゃない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69070/43676), [Does a question using じゃないんじゃない exist?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39755/43676)

Comment: This is a double-negative question. って is a quotation marker used to make this sentence sound more reserved (="I guess"). "That's not a very good thing, is it, I guess".