# What does じゃないじゃん mean? Does this count as a double negative?

Tags: translation, negation

[image]

じゃないじゃん from context she seems to be it's the time to support that girl?

and "I don't have more free time.  Pull yourself together"

Comment: じゃん is just used as a way to emphasize, not as a negative.

Comment: but isn't じゃない already doing "isn't it" then?

Comment: The じゃない is literally the negation. Related [Meaning of じゃないんじゃない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69070)

Comment: Also [Does a question using じゃないんじゃない exist?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39755) [私は母さんを助けたかったんじゃない (Negative or not?)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/88684)

Answer (score 5):

In an uncontracted polite form, it would be 応援している場合では**ない**では**ない**ですか and this is a double negative in the sense that it contains two negative words, but not the kind in which they cancel out each other. A literal English translation that retains the double negative structure would be something like:

> Do you **not** think you should **not** be cheering for that girl?

But since じゃん comes at the end of a sentence, it should be easier to understand it if you simply saw it as something like "right?" or "don't you think?" that you put at the end of a sentence in English.

Comment: What is the first janai doing then?

Comment: @Bluegate - negating 応援している場合だ, of course.

Comment: "if you simply saw it as something like "right?" or "don't you think?" that you put at the end of a sentence in English." - or like the French "n'est-ce pas?"

Comment: But aren't they say they should cheer the girl?

Comment: @Bluegate - No, she is suggesting the other girl (Asuka) should be spending her time or energy for herself.

Comment: ? But then why is the answer "Somehow I missed the timing"? The part before this they ask asuka "What happend to the girl was going to confess to Shuu?" and Asuka replied "I don't know" to which they reply this

Comment: @Bluegate - Then she could be suggesting Asuka should confess herself and Asuka is saying she missed the timing to do so. Whatever the context, the sentence means what I explained it does. You would have to figure out the rest.